# Ruby, run from command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

I have my code:

```
class String
  def freq
    str = String "a string!"
    self.upcase.each_char { |c| puts c + "!" }
    str = text.split("  ")
    wordFrequencies = Hash.new(0)
    str.each { |str| wordFrequencies[str] += 1 }
    wordFrequencies = wordFrequencies.sort_by {|a, b| b }
    wordFrequencies.reverse!
    wordFrequencies.each { |str, wordFrequencies | puts str + " " + wordFrequencies.to_s }
  end
end
```

When I go to run it from the command line, I do:

```
ruby filename.rb
```

and then nothing happens - can anyone explain why..?

Comment: You write that many line before realizing that it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happens because you do nothing in the file.

To have some output you'd want to add

```
String.new.freq
```

as the last line of the file.

Alternatively, you can add the following line before the last `end`:

```
new.freq # create an instance of the class and call `freq` method on it
```

Both options would result in `freq` method being *actually called* and produce output.